# Android Studio crash google Geo Api

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm having a little problem with my app. It crashes and when I run it on Debug it doesn't say anything. This is where the crash occurs:

```
public class GeoTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,ArrayList<Double>>{

@Override
protected ArrayList<Double> doInBackground(String... params) {

    ArrayList<Double> geo_ll = new ArrayList<>();
    HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String result ="";

    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=New York&key=AIzaSyBpaGooTWbj7QbN_qdW4pf-OvAi2OOhpG4");

        connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        int code = connection.getResponseCode();
        int a = 1;

        if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){

            return null;
        }

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));



        String line = reader.readLine();
        while(line!=null){
            result+=line;
            line = reader.readLine();
        }

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray results = object.getJSONArray("results");
        JSONObject zero = results.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONObject geometry = zero.getJSONObject("geometry");
        JSONObject location = geometry.getJSONObject("location");
        double latitude = location.getDouble("lat");
        double longitude = location.getDouble("lng");

        geo_ll.add(latitude);
        geo_ll.add(longitude);

        return geo_ll;

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Toast.makeText(NewItemActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(NewItemActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(NewItemActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    return null;
}
```

I can't see anything wrong. I have checked it more then 100 times and still it happens. It actually worked once and then never worked again after...

please help.
thank you for your time.

Comment: oops the api key is there i will change it to get a new one , for now i'll keep it up for testing , sorry about that.

Comment: `Toast.makeText` has to be called on UI thread, while entire `doInBackground` is called on background thread. Use `e.printStackTrace()` and see the logs instead of showing toasts

Comment: yeah i removed it but still it crashes

Comment: Post your error stacktrace

Comment: how do i find the stacktrack ? cause i dont see any errors

Comment: `but still it crashes` - it is expected. this changes should clarify the cause of the crash. See logcat for the stacktraces, they should be white, not red.

Comment: it still crashes cause i get connection.getRosponseCode 400 or something it exits there , however i added Internet Permissions to the manifest so i dont understand the problem it might be google api or something dont know..